# VARCHAR to DATETIME conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a `varchar` column to `datetime` in SQL server 2014.  I've tried the following and I can get the `date` and `minute` portions fine, but can't get the `hour` part correctly.  Is it possible to get `hour` part?

Here is an example:

```
Select
    mt.DatevarcharCol, 
    RIGHT(mt.DatevarcharCol, LEN(mt.DatevarcharCol) - CHARINDEX(',',mt.DatevarcharCol)) AS 'Number to the right of',
    DATEADD(DAY, CAST(  SUBSTRING(mt.DatevarcharCol, 1, charindex(',', mt.DatevarcharCol) - 1)  AS bigint),(CONVERT(datetime,'12/31/1840'))) AS 'Date part',
    ((RIGHT(mt.DatevarcharCol, LEN(mt.DatevarcharCol) - CHARINDEX(',',mt.DatevarcharCol))) % 86400)%3600/60 AS Minute,
    ?? -- calculate hour part 
FROM  dbo.mytable mt
```

*Result*:

```
DatevarcharCol Number to the right of Date part           Minute hour
-------------- ---------------------- ------------------- ------ ----
63402,67524    67524                  2014-08-03 00:00:00 45     ??
```

Answer (score 1):

The hour would be:

```
(RIGHT(mt.DatevarcharCol, LEN(mt.DatevarcharCol)-CHARINDEX(',',mt.DatevarcharCol)))/60/60%24
```

The seconds would be:

```
(RIGHT(mt.DatevarcharCol, LEN(mt.DatevarcharCol)-CHARINDEX(',',mt.DatevarcharCol)))%60
```

Also, I suggest you don't store comma separated values in a single column. Instead, put each value in its own column.

Comment: Thanks Radu.  I tried your suggestion for hour part and get 18 hrs for varchar column 63402,67524 and 19 hrs for 63402,67524.  For example, 63402,67524 hour/minute would be 01:45 and for 63591,69034 hr/minute 03:10.  I'm getting the minute part correct for varchar column 45 & 10.

Comment: @IYO Why would 67524 be 01:45? Aren't these numbers the time of day in seconds passed? I think it would be correct for it to be like this ( 18*60*60 + 45*60 + 24 = 67524) . Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/518)

Comment: Radu - no it doesn't have seconds 01:45:00.000 [63402,67524] & 03:10:00.000 [63591,69034]
(getting 18 hrs for varchar column 63402,67524 and 19 hrs for 63591,69034)

Comment: @IYO Please allow me to exclamate: "Oh my God!" .. you are storing time intervals (From & To) codified as integers and concatenated into a single column and you want their difference as hours & minutes. This is a very bad design!

Comment: :( I know it's weird - that's how client is storing datetime in their database.